# One-to-one and one-to-many data formats in ArangoDB

Tags: database, database-design, arangodb

New to graph modeling and ArangoDB, I am trying to replace a relational database. For one-to-one or one-to-many relations, I'm struggling to find a correct way to structure my documents and edges.

[image: UML representation of database]

For example, to replace tables `auth_credentials`, `auth_fb`, `auth_google` which contains information allowing users to log in with different services (username-password, facebook, google). I can imagine 3 ways of structuring the data:

- Create collections `auth_*` with the authentication information, and edgeCollections `auths_users` to link them to users. This matches well the schema above, but I find it cumbersome to create 1 document and 1 edge for each authentication object.
- In my `users` documents, have a attribute `auths` which contains arrays of objects with authentication information. I expect it would be difficult to query users based on some authentication information, and this is probably missing the point of graphs.
- Create edgeCollections `auth_*`, with `_from` and `_to` linking to the handle of the user that own the authentication information.

I like the last option better, but I'm fearing it is an antipattern to have edgeCollections where we always have `_from == _to`. Similarly for `groups`, I would make them edges from and to their administrator.

To summarize: to represent data B that belongs to data A, is it a good approach to create an edge (from A to A) containing the data of B?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't sound like a graph use case. There are only three auth types (credentials, facebook, google) and the authentication information is not shared with multiple users. Thus, I would embed the auth data in the user document:

```
{
    "_id": "user/1234",
    "auth": {
        "credentials": { ... },
        "facebook": { ... },
        "google": { ... }
    }
}
```

The nested attributes are optional, e.g. if there isn't any data for a Google auth, simply leave the "google" attribute away.

The attribute paths are very easy to access, e.g. `auth.credentials`. You can also create indexes on the sub-attributes if necessary. With arrays, there are some limitations in that regard, and it is a bit more complicated to get a certain auth info from an array (unless you define a fixed order, i.e. credentials at array index 0 etc., but your data structure wouldn't be self-descriptive anymore).

This is also the most performant solution, because it is a single document read to retrieve user + auth information.